# Getting KeyError when parsing JSON containing three layers of keys, using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm building a Python program to parse some calls to a social media API into CSV and I'm running into an issue with a key that has two keys above it in the hierarchy. I get this error when I run the code with PyDev in Eclipse.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 413, in <module>
    main()
  line 390, in main
postAgeDemos(monitorID)
  line 171, in postAgeDemos
    age0To17 = str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN"])
KeyError: 'ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN'
```

Here's the section of the code I'm using for it. I have a few other functions built already that work with two layers of keys.

```
import urllib.request
import json

def postAgeDemos(monitorID):
 print("Enter the date you'd like the data to start on")
 startDate = input('The date must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD. ')
 print("Enter the date you'd like the data to end on")
 endDate = input('The date must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD. ')
 dates = "&start="+startDate+"&end="+endDate
 urlStart = getURL()
 authToken = getAuthToken()
 endpoint = "/monitor/demographics/age?id=";
 urlData = urlStart+endpoint+monitorID+authToken+dates
 webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
 fPath = getFilePath()+"AgeDemographics"+startDate+"&"+endDate+".csv"
 print("Connecting...")
 if (webURL.getcode() == 200):
    print("Connected to "+urlData)
    print("This query returns information in a CSV file.")
    csvFile = open(fPath, "w+")
    csvFile.write("postDate,totalPosts,totalPostsWithIdentifiableAge,0-17,18-24,25-34,35+\n")
    data = webURL.read().decode('utf8')
    theJSON = json.loads(data)
    for i in theJSON["ageCounts"]:
        postDate = i["startDate"]
        totalDocs = str(i["numberOfDocuments"])
        totalAged = str(i["ageCount"]["totalAgeCount"])
        age0To17 = str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN"])
        age18To24 = str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["EIGHTEEN_TO_TWENTYFOUR"])
        age25To34 = str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["TWENTYFIVE_TO_THIRTYFOUR"])
        age35Over = str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["THIRTYFIVE_AND_OVER"])
        csvFile.write(postDate+","+totalDocs+","+totalAged+","+age0To17+","+age18To24+","+age25To34+","+age35Over+"\n")
    print("File printed to "+fPath)
    csvFile.close()
 else:
    print("Server Error, No Data" + str(webURL.getcode()))
```

Here's a sample of the JSON I'm trying to parse.

```
{"ageCounts":[{"startDate":"2016-01-01T00:00:00","endDate":"2016-01-02T00:00:00","numberOfDocuments":520813,"ageCount":{"sortedAgeCounts":{"ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN":3245,"EIGHTEEN_TO_TWENTYFOUR":4289,"TWENTYFIVE_TO_THIRTYFOUR":2318,"THIRTYFIVE_AND_OVER":70249},"totalAgeCount":80101}},{"startDate":"2016-01-02T00:00:00","endDate":"2016-01-03T00:00:00","numberOfDocuments":633709,"ageCount":{"sortedAgeCounts":{"ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN":3560,"EIGHTEEN_TO_TWENTYFOUR":1702,"TWENTYFIVE_TO_THIRTYFOUR":2786,"THIRTYFIVE_AND_OVER":119657},"totalAgeCount":127705}}],"status":"success"}
```

Here it is again with line breaks so it's a little easier to read.

```
{"ageCounts":[{"startDate":"2016-01-01T00:00:00","endDate":"2016-01-02T00:00:00","numberOfDocuments":520813,"ageCount":
{"sortedAgeCounts":{"ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN":3245,"EIGHTEEN_TO_TWENTYFOUR":4289,"TWENTYFIVE_TO_THIRTYFOUR":2318,"THIRTYFIVE_AND_OVER":70249},"totalAgeCount":80101}},
{"startDate":"2016-01-02T00:00:00","endDate":"2016-01-03T00:00:00","numberOfDocuments":633709,"ageCount":
{"sortedAgeCounts":{"ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN":3560,"EIGHTEEN_TO_TWENTYFOUR":1702,"TWENTYFIVE_TO_THIRTYFOUR":2786,"THIRTYFIVE_AND_OVER":119657},"totalAgeCount":127705}}],"status":"success"}
```

I've tried removing the ["sortedAgeCounts"] from in the middle of

```
age0To17 = str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN"])
```

but I still get the same error. I've remove the 0-17 section to test the other age ranges and I get the same error for them as well. I tried removing all the underscores from the JSON and then using keys without the underscores.

I've also tried moving the str() to convert to string from the call to where the output is printed but the error persists.

Any ideas? Is this section not actually a JSON key, maybe a problem with the all caps or am I just doing something dumb? Any other code improvements are welcome as well but I'm stuck on this one.

Let me know if you need to see anything else. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the output of `print str(i["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"])`?

Comment: Are you sure that _every_ element of that array has those keys? The thing to do in this situation is to start using `print` statements or a debugger to see where it's going wrong. Try catching the `KeyError` and examining only the failing row.

Comment: I feel there are more problems with the `JSON` you are trying to parse than anything else.

Comment: Yeah @Two-BitAlchemist, I just ran through the JSON and all of them are there in each instance. It just repeats the same thing over and over depending on how many days you call for.

Comment: That might be true @NickilMaveli but it's all I've got to work with. : )

Comment: @nephtes it gives `{'ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN': 3245, 'THIRTYFIVE_AND_OVER': 70249, 'TWENTYFIVE_TO_THIRTYFOUR': 2318, 'EIGHTEEN_TO_TWENTYFOUR': 4289}` I could always build a loop or regex matcher to get these once I get this but it seems like the JSON should work.

Answer (score 0):

Edited(This works):

```
JSON=json.loads(s)        
for i in JSON:
    print str(JSON[i][0]["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN"])
```

`s` is a string which contains the your JSON.

Comment: That gives me a KeyError on 'AgeCounts'. It only appears once in the JSON  which is why my loop is built on top of it. I tried to move the [0] to after ageCount and leave the "i" in the front to maintain the loop like this

    `age0To17 = str(i["ageCount"][0]["sortedAgeCounts"]["ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN"])`

But then I get a Key Error on the 0

Comment: I switched mine up to match yours and now I get this error. `age0To17 = str(theJSON[i][0]["ageCount"]["sortedAgeCounts"]["ZERO_TO_SEVENTEEN"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Make sure you iterate over JSON, i.e, `for i in theJSON:`

Comment: I am but it still gives me the Key Error.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code you are trying to execute? Or just provide any link to it.